# Apache2 wildcard alias

Tags: virtualhost, mod-rewrite, apache2, wildcard-subdomain

I have the following wildcard vHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin hostmaster@example.de
    ServerName autodiscover.*.*
    ServerAlias autoconfig.*.*

    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

But my RewriteRule is wrong.

For Example:

`autoconfig.testdomain.de` gets mapped to `https://autoconfig.testdomain.de`

What I want:

- `autoconfig.*.*` gets mapped to `https://autoconfig.maindomain.de`
- `autodiscover.*.*` gets mapped to `https://autodiscover.maindomain.de`

I want to parse only the subdomain part in `%{HTTP_HOST}` to `subdomain.example.de`, but only if the subdomain part is either `autoconfig` or `autodiscover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%1.maindomain.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

There's no need to check `%{HTTPS} !=on` since you are in the vHost for port 80.

The `RewriteCond` directive captures just the subdomain from the requested hostname (which can only be `autoconfig` or `autodiscover` from the vHost config stated). This is then referenced using the `%1` backreference in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string.

Alternatively, you can explicitly check for only the `autoconfig` or `autodiscover` subdomains in the condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(autoconfig|autodiscover)\.
```

You need to clear your browser cache before testing, since the erroneous 301 (permanent) redirects will have been cached by the browser. Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

> ```
> ServerName autodiscover.*.*
> ```

I guess you must be on an older version of Apache, since you can't use *wildcards* in the `ServerName` directive on newer versions of Apache (it would otherwise create an ambiguity, since the `ServerName` is used to create self-referenctial URLs in certain scenarios). You should only specify *wildcards* in the `ServerAlias` directive.

This should be changed to something like:

```
ServerName autodiscover.something.something
ServerAlias autodiscover.*.*
ServerAlias autoconfig.*.*
```

Comment: this did it, modified it a bit but finally works like a charm, thx